# problem with Recordset

Tags: java, dataset, eclipse-rcp

```
rs = ldao.getLonaAllList(schemeName, memid, TStrCalcdt);
if(!rs.next())
{   
    MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(sh, SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);
    mb.setMessage("No Data Found");
    mb.open()
    return;
}
while (rs.next()) {
 //other code for bringing the dat
}
```

i want to check, if the record doesnot contain the data then it shows the message. but i found the problem that while getting the record in every case, the *first* recordset data is not displayed.
so please can any body help on this. how can i show that the record set does not contain any data without losing my first data in dataset

Comment: @user642391: It will be really helpful if you can explain your problem in the right way. For example, from your code it is not clear how your problem is related to `eclipse-rcp`? What dataset are you talking about? all-in-all your code snippet itself is not compilable let alone convey any thing else.

Comment: @favonius :thanks for suugestion. i am new to stackoverflow so i need to learn a lot. thanks for suggesting me. please do help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rs.next()` **already moves** to the next record and you call it twice before you enter the loop body, it is clear that the first record gets skipped. Replace your `while` loop with a `do`-`while`:

```
do {
  //other code for bringing the dat
} while (rs.next());
```

(All of this assumes you're actually talking about a [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) *or* something with a similar interface).

Comment: thanks that works. it also work by putting rs.beforeFirst berore tha while loop.